# HID Device gets kidnapped by default mac driver

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

My Application wants to access a HID device I plugged in, but claiming the device does not
work because its already claimed by IOHIDDevice Driver.
In order to prevent that I learned, that I should create and install a codeless kext driver
for mac(OSX 10.8.2) to blackbox my device from beeing loaded.

I spent two days already and I did not have any success so far.
In my testcase you can find

- Log from the USB prober
- My codeless kext module
- output from ioreg when my device is attached

It seems i cannot attach a file here.

please download it from http://www.guenther-sohler.net/testcase.tar.gz

Comment: Please provide more information instead of an archive to download.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what level of access you require, HIDAPI http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/ may provide you with what you need. It's a library that uses IOHidManager as a backend on OSX. Works for me on OSX 10.7.5, no dummy driver required.

Answer (score 0):

Check into a code less KEXT to declare your device as available to user space apps.

It is essentially a plist.

For Yosemite and Mavericks, it needs to be signed by an Apple Developer ID approved for KEXT - you need to be a  Developer and apply for that.